# How do I dynamically add rows in custom DefaultTableModel?

Tags: java, swing

I have subclassed `DefaultTableModel` so that my table could show values from enum stored in JComboBox. This works fine provided that I add immediately data to this table in constructor. Let me show you what I mean by that.

```
final List<PageLabel> pageLabels = new ArrayList<>();
// add some data
pageLabels.add(....);
final PageLabelTableModel tableModel = new PageLabelTableModel(pageLabels);
```

The thing is my application gets data from some text file. Only when this file is processed, the application should add the data the table. So, in other words, I'd like to dynamically add rows to the table. In theory it should be easy. In practice, however, it is not. I wrote a simple method to fill the table:

```
public void fillTable(final List<PageLabel> labels) {
   for (final PageLabel label : labels) {
      final Vector<PageLabel> rowData = new Vector<>();
      rowData.add(label);
      tableModel.addRow(rowData);
   }
}
```

It fails with the exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
    at java.base/java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:466)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.justifyRows(DefaultTableModel.java:278)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.insertRow(DefaultTableModel.java:382)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.addRow(DefaultTableModel.java:357)
```

Why is that? Here's my custom table model class:

```
// the code heavily borrows from
// https://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/how-to-create-jcombobox-cell-editor-for-jtable
public class PageLabelTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

   private static final String[] columnNames = { "Label", "Start page", "Style" };

   private final List<PageLabel> pageLabels = new ArrayList<>();

   public PageLabelTableModel() {
      super(columnNames, 0);
   }

   @Override
   public Class<?> getColumnClass(final int column) {
      return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
   }

   @Override
   public int getRowCount() {
      return pageLabels != null ? pageLabels.size() : 0;
   }

   @Override
   public int getColumnCount() {
      return columnNames.length;
   }

   @Override
   public String getColumnName(final int column) {
      return columnNames[column];
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isCellEditable(final int rowIndex, final int columnIndex) {
      return columnIndex >= 0;
   }

   @Override
   public Object getValueAt(final int rowIndex, final int columnIndex) {

      final PageLabel pageLabel = pageLabels.get(rowIndex);

      final Object returnValue;

      switch (columnIndex) {
         case 0 -> returnValue = pageLabel.label();
         case 1 -> returnValue = pageLabel.startPage();
         case 2 -> returnValue = pageLabel.style();
         default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException(
             String.format("Column index %d not found!", columnIndex)
         );
      }

      return returnValue;
   }

   @Override
   public void setValueAt(final Object value, final int rowIndex, final int columnIndex) {

      final PageLabel pageLabel = pageLabels.get(rowIndex);

      switch (columnIndex) {
         case 0 -> pageLabel.label((String) value);
         case 1 -> pageLabel.startPage((int) value);
         case 2 -> pageLabel.style((LabelStyle) value);
         default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException(
             String.format("Column index %d not found!", columnIndex)
         );
      }
   }
}
```

As per comment by @Abra I provide the code for PageLabel class:

```
public class PageLabel {

    private String label;
    private int startPage;
    private LabelStyle style;

     // no-args, all-args, getters/setters
     // omitted for brevity
 
}
```

Below is enum used by the above-mentioned class:

```
public enum LabelStyle {

   DECIMAL("Decimal"),
   ROMAN_LOWER("Roman lower"),
   ROMAN_UPPER("Roman upper"),
   LETTER_UPPPER("Letters upper"),
   LETTER_LOWER("Letters lower"),
   NONE("None");

   private final String style;

   LabelStyle(final String style) {
      this.style = style;
   }
}
```

Comment: A [mre] would be helpful, at least for me. If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting one.

Comment: See the `PersonTableModel` example from [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) on how to extend AbstractTableModel to implement a custom model for your PageLabel class.

Comment: This, `private final List<PageLabel> pageLabels = new ArrayList<>();`, is wrong. A DefaultTableModel uses its own data nucleus and you shouldn't try to shadow it as you're doing. Either use the native data nucleus (get rid of this array list) or else extend an AbstractTableModel as @camickr suggests above.

Comment: Thank you for you comments @camickr and  Hovercraft Full Of Eels. I've rewritten the code to use AbstractTableModel as camickr has suggested. I've lost drag&drop feature `DefaultTableModel` gives by default but I will try to implement it using camickr's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you can build on this minimal refactor of your `PageLabelTableModel` class.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class PageLabelTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private static final String[] columnNames = { "Label", "Start page", "Style" };
    private final List<PageLabel> pageLabels;

    public PageLabelTableModel() {
        this(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public PageLabelTableModel(List<PageLabel> labels) {
        pageLabels = labels;
    }

    public void addRow(PageLabel label) {
        pageLabels.add(label);
        int count = getRowCount();
        fireTableRowsInserted(count, count);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return pageLabels == null ? 0 : pageLabels.size();
    }

    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        Class<?> theClass;
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                theClass = String.class;
                break;
            case 1:
                theClass = Number.class;
                break;
            case 2:
                theClass = LabelStyle.class;
                break;
            default:
                theClass = Object.class;
        }
        return theClass;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Object value;
        PageLabel pageLabel = pageLabels.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                value = pageLabel.getLabel();
                break;
            case 1:
                value = Integer.valueOf(pageLabel.getStartPage());
                break;
            case 2:
                value = pageLabel.getStyle();
                break;
            default:
                value = null;
        }
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(final int rowIndex, final int columnIndex) {
       return columnIndex >= 0;
    }
}
```

- Classes that extend `AbstractTableModel` **must** implement the following three methods:

  1. `getRowCount`
  2. `getColumnCount`
  3. `getValueAt`
- It is also recommended to override other `AbstractTableModel` methods, including:

  1. `getColumnName`
     (Look at code of that method in class `AbstractTableModel` to understand why.)
  2. `getColumnClass`
     (To make use of the default renderers. Refer to [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details.)
  3. `isCellEditable`
     (But you have already overridden this.)
- Note in the `addRow` method, the call to `fireTableRowsInserted`. This is to notify the `JTable` class that the data in the model has changed. Again, refer to *How to Use Tables* for more details.

Also, I added a `toString` method to `LabelStyle`:

```java
public enum LabelStyle {
    DECIMAL("Decimal"),
    ROMAN_LOWER("Roman lower"),
    ROMAN_UPPER("Roman upper"),
    LETTER_UPPPER("Letters upper"),
    LETTER_LOWER("Letters lower"),
    NONE("None");

    private final String style;

    LabelStyle(final String style) {
       this.style = style;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return style;
    }
}
```